# Control google chrome and the major browsers

Tags: c#, google-chrome, browser, programming-languages

Is there any mean to control Google Chrome, firefox, Safari, Opera with any programming language? Is there any com interface or anything similar available to achieve this?

Let's be clear, I don't want to embbed the browsers in my applications, but instead make an application allowing to control installed browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for Protractor. It's a full end-to-end testing tool that works by automating all major browsers. Examples of exactly what you need.

https://github.com/angular/protractor